# SQL Count Customers where Products are the same

Tags: sql, group-by, count

I have a problem. I have a SQL-database named `customers` with the 3 columns `Country`, `CustomerID` and `Product`. With that database, I want to count all the customers which bought the products bike, flask and helmet but grouped by the country as you can see in the following picture.

Is there a chance you can help me out with that? I guess I have to make a join on the same table and make a nested query with another select, but I don't really know how to do that.

I would be very thankful for your help!

[image]

Comment: It is unclear whether the customers have to purchase all three products or any of the products.

Comment: sorry for the late response but in this case i want the customers that purchased all the products mentioned

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to do aggregation in two steps. First find the customers with the 3 different products, then count these customers.

```
SELECT country, count(*)
FROM
(
  SELECT country, CustomerID 
  FROM customers 
  WHERE product IN ('Bike','Flask','Helmet') 
  GROUP BY country, CustomerID
  HAVING COUNT(distinct product) = 3
) dt
GROUP BY country
```

Answer (score 2):

You might use `HAVING` clause along with `GROUP BY` while distinctly count for each customer after counted for those exact three products such as

```
SELECT Country, COUNT(DISTINCT CustomerID) AS Count 
  FROM customers 
 WHERE Product IN ('Bike','Flask','Helmet') 
   AND CustomerID IN ( SELECT CustomerID 
                         FROM customers 
                        GROUP BY CustomerID 
                       HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT Product)=3 )
 GROUP BY Country
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=18685b39fa90e76c53431d601c9f6d8c)</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

Try this sql:

```
select Country,count(distinct CustomerID) 
from customers 
where Product in ('Bike','Flask','Helmet') 
group by Country
```

Answer (score 0):

select Country,count(distinct CustomerID)
from customers
where Product in ('Bike','Flask','Helmet')
group by Country

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT COUNT(CustomerID), Country
FROM Customers
GROUP BY Country
HAVING Product in ('Bike','Flask','Helmet');
```